# Small in arrayformula (Google Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-sheets

I have 5 columns of numbers that I want to sort per row into another set of columns. I figured I need to use small() (e.g. small(a2:e2,1) for f2; small(a2:e2,2) for g2 and so on). Is there away to iterate this for the next rows; if possible using only native google spreadsheet formulas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a temporary work around, but I had to use 3 cheat columns. It looks ok for now but I imagine it will be troublesome for really huge numbers.

Here's a sample sheet for reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQTP2XkRsPRAnPQ5wLhkR8JoNVY6YOExVlOkkX8UeRs/edit#gid=0

The original data are in A3:E

The first cheat column (G3:G) simply creates a column of numbers from 1 to the largest number found in the source data. 1-9 is changed to 01-09 for easier searching. "#" is then added at the end-this will come handy later:

- Cheat Column 1 =filter(if(row(A:A)=max(A:E)+1,ʺ#ʺ,text(row(A:A),ʺ00ʺ)),row(A:A)<=max(A:E)+1)

The second cheat column (H3:H) combines each row into a string separated by "-" with a "#" marker:

- Cheat Column 2=filter(text(A3:A,ʺ00ʺ)&ʺ-ʺ&text(B3:B,ʺ00ʺ)&ʺ-ʺ&text(C3:C,ʺ00ʺ)&ʺ-ʺ&text(D3:D,ʺ00ʺ)&ʺ-ʺ&text(E3:E,ʺ00ʺ)&ʺ#ʺ,A3:A<>ʺʺ)

The last cheat column (I3:I) sorts each line (from cheat column 2) by finding each number from cheat column from 01 up to the max number, then the "#" char (this ensures that each line will still have the # end marker). "Find" will return the "position" of each number or an error if it's not found. By using "if", we can make "find" return the actual number or "" instead.

=filter(arrayformula(if(iferror(find(transpose(filter(G3:G,G3:G<>ʺʺ)),H3:H),ʺʺ), transpose(filter(G3:G,G3:G<>ʺʺ)),ʺʺ)),A3:A<>ʺʺ)

The formula above creates as many columns as there are numbers from cheat column 1. To prevent this, a "-" is added to each number then "Concatenate" is used to combine everything into one massive string with each set separated by "#". The string is then split using the "#" marker.

- Cheat Column 3 =transpose(split(concatenate(filter(arrayformula(if(iferror(find(transpose(filter(G3:G,G3:G<>ʺʺ)),H3:H),ʺʺ),ʺ-ʺ&transpose(filter(G3:G,G3:G<>ʺʺ)),ʺʺ)),A3:A<>ʺʺ)),ʺ#ʺ))

Each number is then separated into each corresponding column by using mid().

- Small 1 =filter(mid(I3:I,2,2)*1,A3:A<>ʺʺ)
- Small 2 =filter(mid(I3:I,5,2)*1,A3:A<>ʺʺ)
- Small 3 =filter(mid(I3:I,8,2)*1,A3:A<>ʺʺ)
- Small 4 =filter(mid(I3:I,11,2)*1,A3:A<>ʺʺ)
- Small 5 =filter(mid(I3:I,14,2)*1,A3:A<>ʺʺ)

Note that the formula above is only for numbers 1-99. For larger numbers, the Text() formulas should have more zeroes to correspond to the number of digits of the biggest number. The Mid() formulas should also be adjusted accordingly.

I would like to stress that I am very far from being a spreadsheet expert and that this solution is very "unoptimized". It requires several cheat columns; with the first one even having more rows than the original data. If anyone can help me get rid of the cheat columns (or at least the first one) I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `SMALL` like you mentioned in your question?

```
=small($A3:$E3,column()-columns($A3:$G3))
```

You will need to change the ranges accordingly. The last `$G$3` is the cell just before the cell where the formula is placed.

[Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13jvKX_vmdkUFEailvCws-oRzORbMKsBcTEUd7zwa3Qk/edit?usp=sharing)